# How do you fix tkinter in python3.8 on wsl?

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to learn GUI based python therefore i was using the Tkinter library. My OS is windows but I have installed Ubuntu wsl as my default terminal, and use wsl vscode as my default text-editor.
I was just creating a basic window using this sample code to check whether it works or not:

```
from Tkinter import *
def onclick():
pass
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello.....")
text.insert(END, "Bye Bye.....")
text.pack()
text.tag_add("here", "1.0", "1.4")
text.tag_add("start", "1.8", "1.13")
text.tag_config("here", background="yellow", foreground="blue")
text.tag_config("start", background="black", foreground="green")
root.mainloop()
```

Turns out it does not work with python3.8.
[Terminal error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UZfN.png)
I looked up multiple resources and forums and could not find any proper solutions. Here are couple of links i have referred to:
https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/ https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224230/how-to-install-tkinter-for-python-3-8 .
A work around I discovered was that installed anaconda which uses python3.7 and used the windows terminal instead (using pycharm not vscode). And it looks like it is functioning properly.
[GUI with python3.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHsvP.png)

The thing is.. I like wsl and vscode far better than windows command line, and I wanted to revert back to it. Is there any solution? I really do not want to fool around with the path too much because I had a bad experience previously (But i am willing to do it again if its going to fix my problem). Thanks for hearing me out.

Comment: You need to use a X-server for Windows. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018) or [here](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2017/02/08/graphical-programs-on-windows-subsystem-on-linux.aspx).

Comment: Please don't post errors as images. They can't be searched, and the visually impaired can't read them at all. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the error directly in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WSL now supports graphical interfaces. In order to use it you need to install or update WSL [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps). Then run your app as usual and your program window should open.

Comment: Note that this approach requires Windows 11 Build 22000 or later.

Comment: ... or Windows 10 Build 19044+.  I tested this on the Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS wsl instance with a basic tkinter app.  This is so cool.

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't Python, but WSL. You can't run anything graphical easily inside WSL. (Microsoft is planning to add that feature, but it isn't ready yet. There are third-party solutions, but they're not that easy to set up.)

The easiest solution is to use a Windows install of Python 3.8 to run your tkinter app. You can still invoke that from inside your Ubuntu WSL, same as any Windows executable.

Comment: Any idea why I'm not able to run python.exe from WSL? `which python.exe` points to the correct dir, `notepad.exe` works fine.. but when i try to run python.exe it does nothing. Also tried with `-i` and `--version` flags (both nothing). Regular python installed on WSL works.

Comment: Oh and I can run python.exe from the windows command line just fine

Comment: @Olli try using the full absolute path. Something like `/mnt/c/Users/ME/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe` worked when I tried it. The `py.exe` launcher also worked.

Comment: Interesting. which python.exe points to AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe, which doesnt work, but the one in Local/Programs/Python... does work. py.exe also works, so I think i'll use that so I dont have to write the long path every time. Thanks!

Comment: Or you may use a bash alias - include a line like `alias python3.8.exe="/mnt/c/Users/ME/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe"` in the **~/.bashrc** file or equivalent. To use in the same shell you used to edit that file remember to `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Have they been able to get around to fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Even if this threat is old, I will tell about one problem what I´ve noticed and solved for me.
The problem is: if you are using tkinter in python for filedialogs, it try to use the Windows-Fonts for the request (that happend only in wsl).
If you try to start your program, it depend on the distro if they are installed, or not, the package is names somewhat around liberation-font, or ttf-liberation - it differs from Repository to repository and can be find with the search-function of apt. If it is not installed and you try to open the dialog, you will get an error-message.
If you install it, it works fine on wsl.

Hopefully this will help others in that case, of strange Error-messages

P.S.: I´ve tested this with over 10 Distros from MS-Store and after I´ve installed that package on all, my programm works fine, except on ubuntu 22.04, because that distro has problems on initialisation and did not work for me, but with 20.x there is no problem.