# wsl python tkinter not found

Tags: python, tkinter, debian

I am trying to run a programm using wsl. My python programm uses tkinter as a gui libary. When running the script I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/coding/11_python_playground/tim_rechner_bug/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
  File "/home/jan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .PySimpleGUI import *
  File "/home/jan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 140, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

My OS is wsl debian.

I installed python 3.10 from source following this tutorial https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-python-on-ubuntu-linux-system/ .

I found different aproaches to fix this but none of them worked for me.
Here are some solutions that I tried that did not fix the issue.

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

```
sudo apt install tk-dev
```

```
sudo apt install tk
```

```
pip3.10 install tk
```

```
python -m pip install tk-tools
```

Comment: Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/tkinter-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you fix tkinter in python3.8 on wsl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890536/how-do-you-fix-tkinter-in-python3-8-on-wsl)

Comment: Both of your comments are good suggestions. I tried the solutions from Jan Willems commend and they did not work.
The solution from the second comment does not fix the issue either.

Comment: That tutorial is terrible. When building python from source, then you `./configure` you need to specify what optional modules you want. `ssl` is basically required, but in your case you want `tk`. You need all of them to match the behavior of a standard `apt install`

Comment: What flags would I have to set @mousetail?

Comment: `./configure --help` should show a list of all of them

Comment: Some libraries are automatically included if you have them installed when you run `./configure`, reading more closely it seems `tk` is one of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed with the helpfull comment of @mousetail.

The fix was to use this instead of the configure line in the tutorial:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --with-tcltk-includes='-I/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so /opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib/libtk8.6.so'
```

Thanks for all your efforts to help!